# How to Rename/ Rearrange Filename Format in Windows Batch File to run every hour

Tags: batch-file

Hello i have a CCTV camera that captures image every hour but the filename is

`[IPAddress]_1_201910179144420687_TIMING.jpg`  can anyone Help me Rename it into something like `Cam1_10/172019_9:14.jpg` ?

i only know simple rename when i know the specified filename, however i do not know how to do it automatically when the Camera sends another file with different time.

```
@echo off
rename "199.177.49.224_1_201910179144420687_TIMING.jpg" "Cam1_10/172019_9:14.jpg"
```

Comment: Is that really `201910179144420687` instead of `2019101709144420687`? If yes, do days and months behave the same? That would be a terrible format. A suggestion: You should keep the `YYYY MM DD hh mm` format for easy sorting/finding. Whether you use spaces, `_` or `:`or nothing as separators doesn't matter (as long as it's consistent). Also, you need a plan for more than one picture per minute (adding seconds/milliseconds too? Adding a counter?)

Comment: You cannot have the filename you have shown. Windows doesn't accept **`:`**  characters in file/directory names.

Comment: Neither can you have `/` in a file name...

Comment: As there was no indication of OS, @aschipfl, I wasn't willing to assume that `Cam1_10` was an intended filename, it could quite easily be a directory and a non Windows path separator, **`/`**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable substitution to automatically rename the files, you can however not have a forward slash in your filename so I substituted it with an underscore:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
   set "line=%%~a"
   ren "!line!" "Cam!line:~15,1!_!line:~21,2!_!line:~23,2!!line:~17,4!_!line:~25,1!_!line:~26,2!.%%~xa"
)
```

You will however notice though that the above will go corrupt once you hit the double digit hours and the position now shifts, but I will leave that to you to figure out. **Hint** look at `if /?` from cmdline to see how you can possibly test `%line:~25,1%` and add a zero if it is a single digit hour.